# How to select all values of checkbox when selectAll is selected?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all the id values of the selected checkboxes. When the user hits "selectAll", all the checkboxes are checked, but I just can't get their individual value. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is the jQuery:

```
        $(".selectAll").unbind("click").click(function(e){//needs work here
        var bool = $(this).is(":checked"); //gets whether selected or not
        var list = new Array();

        $(function(){
            $("input:checkbox").attr("checked", bool);

            if(bool == true){
            $.each((".delID :checked"),function(){
                list.push( $(this).val());
                alert( $(this).val());
            }); }
        });
    }); //END of needs work area.
```

and here is the html:

```
<form name="selectDelete" class="selectDelete">
<table id="inboxTable" class="txt13" width="800px">
<tr><th align="left" style="text-decoration:underline"><input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" class="selectAll"/></th>
    <th style="text-decoration:underline">To</th><td width="20px"></td>
    <th style="text-decoration:underline">Subject
    </th><td width="20px"></td>
    <th style="text-decoration:underline">Date</th><td width="20px"></td>
    <th style="text-decoration:underline">Action</th></tr>

<?php while($info=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $info['id']; ?>

    echo "<tr>
            <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" name="delID" class="delID" value="'.$id.'"/></td>";
```

Just for anybody out there with similar problems, this is what I ended up doing to make the code work:

```
                if(bool == true){
            $(".delID").each(function(index,element){ 
                //list.push( $(this).val());
                alert(index + " " + $(this).val());
            }); }
```

In my case, if 'bool == true', then all the checkboxes will ALWAYS be checked, so that's why using just .delID, instead of .delID :checked worked for me. 
Thanks to all for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$(".delID:checked").each(function(){
    list.push( $(this).val());
    alert( $(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/daQSM/

Comment: Yes, I eventually figured it out myself. Thanks for your kind input.